# Proving stability of an equilibrium of $y'(t)=f(y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Suppose $y(t)$ is a real function satisfying $y'(t)=f(y(t))$ for some smooth $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)<0$.

> if $|y(0)|$ is small enough, do we necessarily have $y(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$?

I think a theorem I learned is a high dimensional generalization of it, but I want a "simple" proof.

Comment: I edited your title, replacing the $t$ in $f(t)$ with $y$ to make it $f(y)$, which seems to be more consistent with the body of your question.  Cheers!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "$f(y), f(0), $ and $f'(0)$"? $y$ is a function while $0$ is a number. What exactly is $f$?

Comment: Perhaps the following proof strategy works?  Informally, with $|y|$ small enough, $f(y)$ is arbitrarily close to a $-my$ for some fixed (because $f$ is smooth) $m>0$.  So $y(t)$ is arbitrarily close to $e^{-mt}$, which goes to zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$f'(0)< 0$, and $f'$ continuous ( assume that) implies that there exists $\delta>0$ so that on $(-\delta, \delta)$ we have $f'<0$ so $f$ is strictly decreasing, and so $f>0$ on $(-\delta, 0)$ and $f<0$ on $(0, \delta)$. Therefore, for $y \in (-\delta, \delta)$, $y\ne 0$ we have
$$y \cdot f(y)<0$$

Now consider the function $t\mapsto y(t)^2/2$. One can see that if $y(0)\in (-\delta,0)\cup (0, \delta)$ then $y^2/2$ is strictly decreasing.

Say $y(0)>0$. Then $y(t)$ is decreasing for $t\ge 0$. Let $l = \lim_{t\to \infty} y(t)$. We have $l\ge 0$. Since the limit of $y(t)$ at $\infty$ is  finite, there exists $t_n\to \infty$ so that $y'(t_n)\to 0$. ( the $t_n \in (n,n+1)$ intermediate points for Lagrange theorem). So $f(y(t_n))\to 0$. But $f(y(t_n))\to f(l)$. Therefore $l=0$.

Btw, $y^2/2$ would be called a Liapounov function.

Comment: What if the third derivative was negative and the lower derivatives would vanish? I expect the theorem to hold (for odd orders). Is there  an analogous method?

Comment: @Emolga: Yes, a similar way one shows that $y \cdot f(y)< 0$ for $0<|y|$ small.  The fastest way would be to use the Taylor approximation.  I guess the rule is that the solution behaves as if $f(y) = k y^m$, where $m$ if the order of $f$ at $0$, and $k$ is the corresponding constant.

Comment: @Emolga: added more details as to why the solution converges to the equilibrium point $0$.